# Clarification of Saturation-Reset Regimes

Tags: portfolio-management, algorithmic-trading

I have worked my way through this [article](http://www.engr.wisc.edu/ece/faculty/barmish_ross/FILE_07.pdf), waiting to get into school I have been self-learning a bit. I have a good grasp on most of the article, but the component strategy of Saturation and Reset are a little confusing to me.

When the control parameter exceeds it's defined maximum, the article stipulates Saturation events occur.

$$I(k^* + j + 1) = \min\{I(k^*+j) + K\Delta g(k^*+j), I_\textrm{max}\}$$

Does this formula found on page 3 mean when the value of the position exceeds the maximum position allowed by the control parameter, excess is liquidated until the position is under the maximum? If not, what is going on here? Is the position simply treated as the maximum, if so, why?

Thanks for any helps.

Comment: Hi Tan Dollars, welcome to Quant.SE! I edited the question to make 'article' point to the paper and set some new tags after reading the abstract.

Comment: thanks! Kdg was supposed to say K delta g though, it has different meaning without the delta